# Tree structure with multiples classes association as a successor

Tags: python, django, model, decision-tree

I'm trying to create a Decision Tree structure with multiple classes resulting of a node but I don't know what's the best way to do this with Django.

To make it clear, here's what I want to do (left son is the case when the condition is valid, right son is when the condition is invalid):

```
           (Condition A)
                |
         -------------------------------
        |                               |
    (Condition B)                 (Condition C)
        |                               |
   ------------------                   |------------
  |                 |                   |           |
(Cond D)    <Category> + <Group>     <Cat>+<Gr>    (Cond D)
  |                                                    |
  ..                                                  ...
```

The idea is to associate a couple (`<Category>`,`<Group>`) or another `<Node>` as a son. The problem is, "How to represent multiple classes field in Django ?"

Here's my model :

```
class GroupDecision(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # Other fields that may come later

class DecisionTree(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    start_node = models.ForeignKey('Node')
    # Other fields that may come later

class Node(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    predecessor = models.ForeignKey('Node', null = True, blank = True, default = None)
    successor = models.ForeignKey('SuccessorAssociation')
    operation = models.ForeignKey('Filter')

class SuccessorAssociation(models.Model):

    TARGET = (('C','Category'),('G','Group'),('N','Node'))

    condition = models.BooleanField()
    target_class = models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=TARGET)
    target_pk = models.IntegerField()
```

I managed to "hack" it with the `SuccessorAssociation` who can target either a `<Category>`,`<Group>` or `<Node>` but I don't like this implementation because it doesn't keep the recursive delete principe without overriding the `delete()` method.

On top of that, I'm overriding some mechanisms who are managed by Django itself.

A custom field would be a way to solve this problem but I'm not really familiar with it and I think that this is a disproportionate way to do.

Can someone help me to implement this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `contenttypes` framework and generic foreign keys: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations